# How to redirect to login screen on token expiry or in error occurrence in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to manage login/logout session with a dedicated class(SessionManager) which is inheriting from ObservableObject. For the API call I have created a singleton global class. I want to redirect the user to login screen if I get the status code as 500 so I am just trying to access SessionManager class in NetworkAPI singleton class but I am getting the runtime error as **Thread 14: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type SessionManager found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for SessionManager may be missing as an ancestor of this view.**. What could be the approach to achieve.

SessionManager class

```
class SessionManager: ObservableObject {

enum CurrentState {
    case loggedIn
    case loggedOut
}

init() {
    let userInfo = UserInfo.shared.getCurrentUserDetails()
    if (userInfo?.authToken ?? "") != "" {
        currentState = .loggedIn
    } else {
        currentState = .loggedOut
    }
}

@Published private(set) var currentState: CurrentState?

func signIn() {
    currentState = .loggedIn
}

func signOut() {
    UserInfo.shared.removeUserInfo()
    currentState = .loggedOut
}
```

}

// APINetwork class

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
class APINetwork {
    static let shared = APINetwork()
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionManager
    
    func postAPICall<T:Codable>(
        url: String,
        param: [String: Any],
        expecting: T.Type,
        completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>)->Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            return
        }
        
        
        let finalData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpBody = finalData
        request.httpMethod = "post"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
        
        let userDetails = UserInfo.shared.getCurrentUserDetails()
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    let respObj = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(respObj))
                } else {
                    print("LoginViewModel-> no data found")
                }
            } catch(let error) {
                print("Error A123")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    func getAPICall<T:Codable>(
        urlString: String,
        inpParam: Any?,
        expecting: T.Type,
        passToken:Bool = true,
        completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>)->Void
        ) {
        let urlForRequest = urlString
        let strEscaped = urlForRequest.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
        let strUrl = URL(string: strEscaped!)
        var request = URLRequest(url: strUrl!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 100)
        
        if passToken {
            let userDetails = UserInfo.shared.getCurrentUserDetails()
            if let authToken = userDetails?.authToken {
                let headers = ["Content-Type": authToken]
                request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            } else {
                let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
                request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            }
            
        }
        
        request.httpMethod = "get"
        
        
//        if inpParam != nil {
//            request.httpBody =  try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: inpParam!, options: [])
//        }
        
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
            do {
                
                if error != nil {
                    print("Heee \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                }
                
                if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    
                    switch httpResponse.statusCode {
                    case 500:
                        //UserInfo.shared.removeUserInfo()
                        self.session.signOut()
                        print("error occured")
                    default:
                        print("deafult")
                    }
                
                }
                
                
                if let data = data {
                    let responseData = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
                    print("APINetwork: String Response \(responseData)")
                    
                }
                
                
                if let data = data {
                    let respObj = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(respObj))
                } else {
                    print("\(self) no data found")
                }
            } catch(let error) {
                print("Error A124 \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

// App delegate

```
import SwiftUI
@main
struct SwiftUIIPMSApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(SessionManager())
        }
    }
}
```

// ContenView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionManager
    var body: some View {
        if session.currentState == .loggedIn {
            HomeView()
        } else {
            LoginView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only use  environment objects in views. Even if you could use the environment, it isn't the correct approach, architecturally. You are coupling you api to your model. Your api class should report the failure, by `throw`ing, for example. The caller can then catch this and take the appropriate action

Comment: then I will have to handle the server token expiry code in each ViewModel, which is not good approch

Comment: I would handle it in my router view model, not in each view model.

Comment: @Paulw11 I’m actually in a similar situation.  I do not have a router view model pattern set up. Is there another option for making this work?

Comment: Nothing that is particularly manageable or scalable. Create a root routing view that shows an appropriate view hierarchy based on the logged in state. Have that view make its decision based on an observable property updated by your session